# Customizing password hashing

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need to use sha-256 for hashing passwords. I have been searching for information but I have not found any thing situable for backpack. I have found some post about changing it for laravel, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the built-in Backpack auth with the instructions here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/base-how-to#customizing-the-auth-controllers . Then, you'll be able to add routes to your own Auth controllers, where you can use your own hashing algorithm instead of bcrypt.

Alternatively, you can stop using the Backpack auth entirely, and only use the Authentication that Laravel comes with.